# Why so many Reboots

Tags: reboot

I have a site that has 3 servers running Ubuntu 14.04.2. In the last couple of weeks I have had several updates that require a system reboot. I ran a system running unix that went years without a reboot. To me this is nerve wracking, much too much monitoring, these systems are at remote (to me) locations. Is this normal for linux systems? Can I not update for a year or 3?

Comment: You have the option to never reboot. some tips for never rebooting: do not update your kernel. You might be interested in Ksplice from Oracle which allows you to update a kernel and not reboot. http://www.ksplice.com/

Answer (score 0):

In the last days, several major security issues were discovered in fundamental libraries in Unix world, like `glibc`, `ssh`, etc. Not to count the kernel upgrade itself.

In theory, you can close and restart all programs relying on `libc`, but probably you'll spend more time finding all and restarting them than with a simple reboot.

For kernel updates, you can use, for now, [Oracle Ksplice](http://www.ksplice.com/): it'll live patch the kernel.

Why "for now"? Because Kernel 4.0 will include this feature by default.